# what does "not many" equal?

Tags: meaning

Does **not many** imply *a very small number* or just *a small number*?
Imagine **many** is around roughly 100, then what does **not many** equal?

Comment: I think you want to say, "Imagine 'many' is around roughly 100." (When you say "equal", then "not many" means "not equal," so 99 would be "not many.") Also, how many is "not many" is very context dependent. The question _How many games did the Tigers win last year?_ can be answered with "not many," but "not many" could be 70, 30, 10, or 3, depending on the sport and the length of the season.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the precise number meant by "not many," it's not definite.  It heavily depends on the context, and is often used when the speaker/writer does not know precisely him/herself, or wishes to hide that information.

In almost all cases, it's OK to ask "How many exactly?" if you need to know precisely.  If the speaker takes offense, he/she is being unreasonable unless you can see for yourself how many or there is no way to precisely tell.

---

"Not many" can typically directly substitute for "a few" or "only a few" without a problem.

> There are a few pieces of candy.
>
> There aren't many pieces of candy.

As far as the plain "few," you can still use "not many," but since verbs you will use with this will be in the negative, you'll probably need to change the sentence to be consistent with how English expresses negative verbs.

> I have few ways of protecting myself.
>
> I do not have many ways of protecting myself.

*I have not many ways of protecting myself* is grammatically correct, but sounds jarring (at least from my AmE point of view, BrE may be different.)

> There are few ways out of town.
>
> There aren't many ways out of town.

There are probably other examples I can't think of at the moment.

*Few and far between* is a well-known phrase and it should never be *not many and far between.*

Comment: Pardon me! What do you mean by "Few and far between is a well-known phrase and it should never be not many and far between"?

Comment: It's an idiom, that's how I should have put it.

Answer (score 2):

If roughly 100 termites is many termites in my kitchen, then not many termites in my kitchen can be anywhere from 0 to 99. The word 'not many' does not depend only upon a statement of quantity (how many) but also the speakers attitude toward the object being quantified (described with many/not many).

If roughly 100 children are playing at the park on a Saturday afternoon and that is considered many, then for that same Saturday 'not many' might be anywhere from, say, 15 to 45. But that is a rough figure and few will give you the same range. You really have to decide for yourself what many and not many mean for you in any given context.

Comment: Except 99 is "roughly 100".